# Change the "about this" window on mac app

Tags: java, macos, deployment

On Macs, there's a default menu at the top for basic application handling functions:

[image: Editor menu bar]

I've made an application using Java for my Grade 10 final project, (and I'm quite convinced that it's better than Microsoft Paint) and I decided to package it. Using Eclipse, I exported it as a Mac OS X Application Bundle. However, I want to change the "About Editor" on the default menu. Currently, it shows this:

[image: About Editor]

How can I change the contents of the About Window (My app is definitely not Version 1.0.1)? I'm hoping not to go into Xcode or anything, but is there something that I can change with something like `System.setProperty(key, value)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your application is an `.app bundle` then it should have an `info.plist`. Inside the `info.plist` will normally contain version information that should display the version number:

```
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>2.0.0</string>
```

Typically the version information here is populated in places that call for it (eg. About). To change the name that would display on the menu and within the about dialog box:

```
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>My Application</string>
```

Copyright Info:

```
<key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
<string>Copyright © 2015 Your Company</string>
```

Bundle Icon File:

```
<key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
<string>icon.icns</string>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved the version issue, but I don't think I made my entire question clear: Can I change the entire contents of the window?

Comment: Yes, definitely — I missed the part about the name change on the menu; examples added.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot! I see the `info.plist` and I'm looking into everything right now. :D